# How to Initialize a Struct?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, struct

I have a struct like so :

```
struct fooStruct {
  uint foo;
  uint figther;
}
```

I would like to initialize that struct but it won't be stored in a mapping but inside an array.

Is there a way to initialize the struct like

`fooStruct myStruct = fooStruct.new(par1,2,3)`

Comment: good question.  Not covered well in the solidity docs.  This saved me a goo dchunk of time today.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Yes, just use

```
fooStruct myStruct = fooStruct(1,2);
```

Or

```
fooStruct myStruct = fooStruct({foo:1, fighter:2});
```

Or

```
fooStruct memory myStruct; // for temporary data
myStruct.figther = 2; // will only write to memory

fooStruct storage myStruct = ...; // for persistent data, has to be initialized from a state variable. `storage` is the default and a warning will be thrown by Solidity compiler versions starting with 4.17
myStruct.fighter = 2; // will write directly to storage
```

See the [docs](https://solidity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/types.html#structs) for more examples

Comment: Great! can you do `fooStruct myStruct = fooStruct();`
`myStruct.figther = 2;` ?

Comment: Added an example

Comment: `@Tjaden`, What if one of the members is optional. How should defining the struct or assigning change? Eg: if I want the fighter to have a predefined value or `NULL` value.

Comment: The value of each member will default to the `0` value for that type (`0` for ints, `false` for bools, etc.). If you want to have a "default" value that is different from the "0" value, you can either have a bool that indicates a value was set to "0", as opposed to defaulting to 0. You can also use a trick where you use the most significant bit of each value as the "set" bit, then just use the rest as for the actual value.

Comment: Does solidity array has a `filter`/`first` functions which accept a lambda predicate?

Comment: How to initialize it from outside of the contract scope? E.g. from a test file?