# Initializing structs in solidity

Tags: solidity, contract-development, mix

This question is related to [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1511/how-to-initialize-a-struct) one. I have a structure

```
struct File {
        uint256 fileId;
        uint256 filePrice;
    }

File[] files;
```

and try to initialize it as:

```
File newFile = File(0, 0);
files.push(newFile);
```

but get:

```
Error: Type struct File memory is not implicitly convertible to expected type struct File storage pointer.
```

I don't get which one is the storage and which one is the memory pointer? Is the struct File array stored in memory or as persistent storage?

**Edit**:

I have found the answer/reason [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4467/initialising-structs-to-storage-variables).